# How to prove the cardinality of a closed interval is equal to the continuum?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say we have a closed interval $[a,b]$. How can I prove $|[a,b]|$ equal to $c$, where $c$ is the continuum.

I already proved $|(a,b)| = |(c,d)|$. But I don't know whether it is useful.

Comment: Show cardinality of $[a,b]=(a,b)\cup \{a,b\}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are same.

Comment: Yea, I think that is what $c$ means. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Find a bijection between the two sets.

Comment: Oh I get it. $[a,b]$ belongs to $R$, so I can apply the Schroder-Bernstein theorem! $|(a,b)|\leq R$. For any $(c,d)$ in $R$, $|(c,d)|\leq (a,b)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the fact that: "If $P$ is a non empty perfect set in $\mathbb{R}^k$ then $P$ is uncountable". Show $[a,b]$ is a perfect set.

You may also define a mapping as $f:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]\::\:f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{\pi}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\arctan(x)\right) &x\in(0,1)\\x &x\in\{0,1\}\end{cases}$

Comment: What you wrote in the first paragraph is not enough. You do not simply want to show that intervals are uncountable, as there are many different uncountable cardinalities.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: Yes I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You only need to find an injection $\mathbb R \to [a,b]$. Some such injection can be achieved by modifying $\tan^{-1}$. (It's also possible to construct one by hand that is piecewise linear.)